# Javascript client will not connect to node.js server through websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am trying to connect a client, ran in a web browser, to a server using websockets.

My client is written in javascript and my server is node.js. I have managed to connect a node.js client with my server but cannot seem to connect my javascript client to the server.

server code:

```
var webSocketServer = require("websocket").server;
var http = require("http");
var port = 9000;

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log(new Date() + " Received request");
});

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(new Date() + " listening on port 9000");
});

var socket = new webSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

socket.on("request", function (request) {
    var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

    connection.on("message", function (message) {
        console.log(message.utf8Data);
    });

});
```

client code:

```
var client = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000");

client.onopen = function () {
    client.send("Handshake from client");
}
```

I expected to see the handshake from client output in my command prompt from which I ran my server. This does not happen. In my browsers console I eventually get this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9000/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
```

I tried to `console.log` my client object and the output was this:

```
WebSocket {url: "ws://localhost:9000/", readyState: 0, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: null, onerror: null, …}
```

So as far as I know the object is being built correctly and pointing at the correct URL but still fails to make the connection.

Comment: I ran the exact same code as you and it works perfectly :/

Comment: I have just created a new folder, reinstalled websocket (npm install websocket), added in my code and it know works. I cant for the life of me work out why it wasn't working last night but I had been working on my project for hours so in my tired state I must have missed something. @boehm_s thanks anyway. Your comment did confirm my code was correct so I appreciate that.